# Requirements for using google places library

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In a web app I have set up an adress autosuggest using google places library like this:

```
     autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('AddressSearch')),
          { types: ['geocode'], bounds: region });
...
```

Right now I got into the research of Maps API lincenses and I really got confused about the places API and places librabry. I see that different license rules apply to places API.

But what about places librabry? I cannot seem to find any other requirement than including google's logo. Is that the only requirement?

Any guidance, help, suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Places API and the Places Library in the JavaScript API (as well as the JS API itself) are subject to the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms). The additional requirements on the [Places API policies page](https://developers.google.com/places/policies) are a consequence of these ToS (see section 9 for example) and therefore apply to both.

In general, you should make sure your application complies with the Terms of Services. There's also a few [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq) entries related to the ToS.